# Bootstrap add div and class into my select options

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-5

guys, i  have a template in WordPress that is made by bootstrap, and i have html content in my page but the bootstrap add into my html content a new div and class

**here is my code before use Template has Bootstrap:**

```
   <div class="widget-selectbox-container">
     <select name="like" class="select-meow">
                   <option value="">Select Likes</option>
                   <option value="1">1</option>
                   <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
   </div>
```

**and this is what happens to my HTML content after use the template has bootstrap:**

[Image of my HTML content after using Boostrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a194.png)

so how i can fix this? I want to avoid bootstrap from controlling my select option and div

Comment: If you don't have control over it, removing classes using JS can be a solution.

Comment: As @Akib mentioned you could use javascript to remove the classes but there is also the option to remove the whole element I however would recommend jquery for this as its very simple syntax: `$( ".select-sobex-meow" ).remove();`  You can test if this works by pasting that bit of code into your F12 console.

Comment: @RomeoBeun, i did as you said in the console and it works, but when I put the js code in a file and reload the page it doesn't work, it works only in console

Comment: @deverasha Did you make a reference to your js file in the html file?